# Background image in TabBar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm trying set the background image for a tabbar in my app like in this example,

[Android Design in Action: Transit Apps in the minute 27:16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs8k_PDUL3s&index=37&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF)

My code is:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Divider</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="Divider" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar">


    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

but the picture is stretched

How do I can get the same thing ?

Regards,
racso